# Unable to host API after context use

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to host my API but it's not working. The problem appeared once I moved the initialization code for the database to one place, the Program Main. I narrowed down the problem to that any usage of the db context will cause the application to not host once host.Run() is executed. No exception is thrown but the application isn't properly hosted (I can't access the api url's and the application wont open the default url automatically).

Eventually I figured out if I do host.Run() before I use any method in the db context, the application will work. This is not an optimal solution and I would like to know what the problem is. The context methods are executed properly and I can add stuff to the database, the app just wont host if I use the context before host.Run().

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();

        using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
            try
            {
                var context = services.GetRequiredService<CashinContext>();
                context.Database.EnsureCreated();
                //DbInitializer.Initialize(context);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                logger.LogError(ex, "An error occured while seeding the database.");
            }

        }

        host.Run();

    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

**UPDATE**
By changing the code from,

```
var context = services.GetRequiredService<CashinContext>();
```

To,

```
var context = services.GetService<CashinContext>();
```

it now works. I don't understand why, because `GetRequiredService()` is supposed to throw an exception when there is no service available, no exception was ever thrown. With `GetService()` the function should return null when there is no service available. I checked this by debugging, and null was not returned and everything went good.

Comment: Sounds unrelated. That should work fine. Try turning up the logs to be verbose to see if there's more information.

Comment: Is it the context or is it the lifetime of the scope?

Comment: @davidfowl, That's what I also thought, but it is not working properly. Tried to make the debug console more verbose, but I did not find anything interesting.

Comment: @GertArnold The problem occurs when I use the context before running `host.Run()`.

Comment: @davidfowl Update, so I used GetService() instead, then I switched back to GetRequiredService() and out of nowhere, it seems to work. This really blows my mind and I can't understand why, was debugging yesterday for 5 hours...

Comment: Sounds like there's an exception being thrown or something. Did you attach the debugger and try breaking on all exceptions?